# Conditional use of wp_list_categories (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am using the  wp_list_categories tag in Wordpress.
I would like to wrap this in a condition so it is only used when there are posts in the database. Something like:

```
if ($number_of_posts > "0") {
}
```

But I can't find a function that'll let me count the number of posts. Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

i would use [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) idea with [query posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

something like

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=1');
if(have_posts()) {
   // run code here!
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No worries, just a suggestion but perhaps you could post your solution on here so others can learn from you?

Answer (score 0):

Found this snippet:

```
$num_pages = wp_count_posts( 'page' );     
$num_pages = $num_pages->publish; //publish
```

Which when used as follows, solves my problem:

```
<?php 
if ($num_posts > "0") {
wp_list_categories('title_li=Blog:'); 
}
```